# Set Reverse DNS on Azure

Tags: azure, dns, reverse

I'm trying to set a ReverseDNSFqdn on azure but it returns Internal Error.

This is my command:

```
Set-AzureService –ServiceName my service –Description "Myservice with Reverse DNS" –ReverseDnsFqdn "mail.domain.comt."
```

But after this command hang for a while I get:

```
> VERBOSE: 17:03:37 - Begin Operation: Set-AzureService Set-AzureService
> : InternalError: The server encountered an internal error. Please
> retry the request. OperationID : '305d9e84f7eac9b8be2b007ff06517f2' At
> line:1 char:1
> + Set-AzureService -ServiceName domaincom -ReverseDnsFqdn "mail.doma ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureService], ComputeCloudException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.HostedServices.SetAzureServiceCommand
> 
> VERBOSE: 17:08:37 - Completed Operation: Set-AzureService
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the last parameter is

"mail.domain.comt."

That's not a proper domain and it should refer to an existing Azure domain.  These are the conditions from another error message for the same command:

```
Set-AzureService : BadRequest: The reverse DNS FQDN
mydomain.cloudapp.azure.com. must resolve to one of: 
a). the DNS name of this Hosted Service (MyDomain.cloudapp.net), 
b). the DNS name of a different Hosted Service in this subscription (2463b312-3e47-402d-944c-a38eec7a8286), 
c). a Reserved IP belonging to this subscription, or 
d). the IP of a deployment or of a VM in this subscription.
```